# Finding sibling after matching node text using XPath

Tags: html, xpath

Consider the following HTML.

```
<div class="block table__responsive-body" id="review_2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns hide-for-large-up">
            <strong>Betyg</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns table__responsive-body-content">5<p>
            <strong>Skapades den: </strong>28 jun 09:44</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns hide-for-large-up">
            <strong>Produkt</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns table__responsive-body-content">
            <a href="/products/9">Volvo V50</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns hide-for-large-up">
            <strong>Recensent</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns table__responsive-body-content">
            <a href="/users/24">John Doe</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find the succeeding `div` node for any preceding sibling `div` containing a `strong` node with a given text.

For example: Given the `<strong>` node text to find is `Betyg`. I expect it to return:

```
<div class="small-8 columns table__responsive-body-content">5<p>
    <strong>Skapades den: </strong>28 jun 09:44</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath will do as you describe:

```
//div[strong/text()[contains(., 'Betyg')]]/following-sibling::div
```

Find the `div` containing a `strong` child element, which contains the text `Betyg`. Then find the following sibling that is a `div`.